# merge two exel sheets and update duplicate value

Tags: vba, merge, vlookup

I have two exel sheets and I need to merge this sheets but in sheets 1 i Have 800 records in sheet 2 i have 20 records and some of value from sheets 2 are duplicated in sheet 1. I wan to update duplicated values record in sheet 1

Example sheet 1:

[image]

Example sheet 2:

[image]

Comment: How many values from the duplicate records need to be updated in Sheet 1? Just one, or a bunch of 'em?

Comment: This is usually more than half. But in bad day is more than 100 duplicated records. (sheet 2 ia a update for sheet 1).

Comment: So it's not just the figure in one column?

Comment: example: sheet 1 http://i.imgur.com/cEnhA9i.png sheet 2 http://i.imgur.com/HiSg2kq.png

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is just one column you want to change, [VLookups](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-function-HP010343011.aspx) are the way to go.

In your Sheet 1, insert a column to the right of the original price column, and setup a `VLookup` formula that looks up the price column from Sheet 2 of any duplicate records.  Once you have done that, insert another column to the right of the `VLookup` column with an [If](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/if-function-HP010342586.aspx) function that sets the value equal to the `VLookup` column, or if that is blank, the value from the original column.

Based on your images the `VLookup` formula in cell Q2 would go something like:

```
=VLOOKUP(D2, Sheet2!$A$1:$H$11, 5, FALSE)
```

which you then copy down to the bottom of your data.  Your `If` function in cell R2 will be something like:

```
=If(Q2="", P2, Q2)
```

Copy and Paste Special.../Values the figures in the If column to the original column, delete the two columns you've just inserted, and you should be right.

Comment: Thanx for you answer, this is only for duplicated record, what if i have new record in sheet 2?

Comment: If a record in sheet 2 doesn't exist in sheet 1, you just add the whole row to the first sheet.  It should be easy to determine if you have an extra record if your data is sorted. How to do it automatically sounds like a new question.